# In kotlin hide a button during the listener execution

Tags: android, kotlin, button

I want to hide the button during the entire execution of the onClick listener. And reshow it after the end of the listener.

the code is like this:

```kotlin
    playButton.setOnClickListener {
        playButton.visibility= View.INVISIBLE
        play()
        playButton.visibility= View.VISIBLE
    }
```

During the `play()` function also occurs modification on the view.
What is happening in that the alteration in the view only occur  after the end of the listener. so that all the modifications happens at the same time.
If I comment:

```kotlin
playButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

The button disappears as the elements shown by the play function appears.

Comment: Can you provide the code of the `play()` function? Is it an async fun or a lambda perhaps?

Comment: You could use`Thread{ Thread.sleep(5000) //Your code here }.start()` but this may not apply to your situation. Is the function a suspend function?

Comment: The code for play: 
private fun play(){
        val thread = Thread(
            Runnable {
                Log.d("TAG","1")
                envia()
            }
        )
        thread.start()

        while(thread.isAlive) {
            Thread.sleep(10000)
        }

        val ctx=this.applicationContext
        var file = File(ctx.filesDir,"qrcode-numero.png")
        val qrcode=findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.qrcode)
        qrcode.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file))
    }

Comment: You could use Thread{ Thread.sleep(5000) //Your code here }.start():
Doesn´t work either. Even if I put the sleep in the place of my code the same thing happens, for somo reason that eludes me the code only check for the redraw at the end of the listener.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to solve this problem using the OnTouchListener:

```
playButton.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
        Log.d("TAG","Touch")
        when (motionEvent.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                playButton.visibility= View.INVISIBLE
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                play()
                playButton.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
        view.performClick()
        return@setOnTouchListener true
    }
```